# Start Google Chrome as Guest

Tags: google-chrome

How to start a Google Chrome directly in Guest Mode? Is it any Target field switch like -incognito for Incognito Mode? I'm trying to do this using -profile-directory=Guest but it won't work. Please help.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the command:

```
chrome.exe --guest
```

Comment: This is the best answer, it launches Chrome directly in Guest mode. Linux user should use: `chrome --guest`. Chromium works in similar way: `chromium --guest`.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if it's currently possible to do this. The closest alternative I've found is to right-click your Chrome shortcut, click "Properties", then append `--profile-directory="Guest Profile"` to the "Target" field. That will not open Guest mode directly, but it will open Chrome to the profile selector screen, where guest mode is one click away.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by going to the Settings.

Under 'People' section, click "Add person...", you can name it as "Guest" or anything you want, make sure the checkbox "Create a desktop shortcut for this user" is checked.

Once you've done that, there will be a shortcut in your desktop. You can pin it on your taskbar or just leave it there on the desktop for others to use.

So far, that's the only way I know how to do this. Hope it helps.

Comment: Guest mode won't have persistent memory, so you don't have to worry about 'forgetting' sessions. I think opening with built-in `guest` profile is safer.

Answer (score 0):

What I found is right-click your Chrome shortcut, click "Properties", then append "--bwsi" (= Browse Without Sign In) to the "Target" field. This seems to open a guest mode browser.

Source: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/VcpiO25LoQQ